# Laravel how sort merge collections

Tags: php, collections, laravel-5, merge, query-builder

I have 3 query, my problem is I want the merged collection to be sorted by `created_at`.

How to merge and sort three query builder collections?

```
        $posts1 =\DB::table('posts')
        ->select('posts.*', 'users.nom','pratics.titre')
        ->join('pratics', 'posts.pratic_id','=','pratics.id')
        ->join('users', 'posts.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->where('pratics.user_id',$id)
        ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
        ->get();

        $posts2 =\DB::table('posts')
        ->select('posts.*', 'users.nom','pratics.titre')
        ->join('journals', 'posts.pratic_id','=','journals.id')
        ->join('users', 'posts.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->where('journals.user_id',$id)
        ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
        ->get();


        $posts3 =\DB::table('posts')
        ->select('posts.*', 'users.nom','pratics.titre')
        ->join('exos', 'posts.exo_id','=','exos.id')
        ->join('users', 'posts.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->where('exos.user_id',$id)
        ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
        ->get();

$posts = array_merge($posts1,$posts2, $posts3)->sortby('created_at');
```

Comment: I suggest you to `UNION` all your queries and not to merge those 3 arrays in php.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#unions

Comment: for union like this : $posts1 =\DB::table('posts')->select('posts.*', 'users.nom','pratics.titre')
        ->join('pratics', 'posts.pratic_id','=','pratics.id')->join('users', 'posts.user_id','=','users.id')->where('pratics.user_id',$id);

        $posts2 =\DB::table('posts')->select('posts.*', 'users.nom','pratics.titre')->join('journals', 'posts.pratic_id','=','journals.id')
        ->join('users', 'posts.user_id','=','users.id')->where('journals.user_id',$id)->union($posts1)->get();

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Vitalii Strimbanu that this is probably not the best way to get all your records.

That being said, to answer your question specifically, I believe the only thing you are missing is to make your merged *array* into a *collection* before you call sortby on it:

```
$posts = collect(array_merge($posts1,$posts2, $posts3))->sortby('created_at');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge the collections, use merge() function like this:

```
$posts1->merge($posts2)->merge($posts3)->sortby('created_at');
```

And the `array_merge()` is not workable here. If you want to use `array_merge()`, you have to use `toArray()` before that.